# Core plot - start origin of graph at (0,0)

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

If you see the picture below, what I want is for the graph to start at 0 on the y axis and 6/28 on the x axis. How can I do this using core data? I can't find a way anywhere.

Both these values are 0 for each axis, so why doesn't the graph start at 0?

Plus I don't want negative values or dates.

I want it to start from a corner, like normal graphs. `|_`

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! found it

You have to set:

```
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0");
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert in CorePlot but try setting the visibleRange and gridLinesRange on the x and y CPXYAxis.  Something like this:

```
CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)self.axisSet;     // self is of type CPXYGraph

CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.visibleRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];
x.gridLinesRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(yMax-1)];

CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.visibleRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(yMax - 1.0f)];
y.gridLinesRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];

// Set axes
self.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

While I am searching for the solution of similar problem. I realise "CPDecimalFromFloat" is invalid . Later on Found out that CPDecimalFromFloat no longer there but I can use "CPTDecimalFromFloat".